# Reset Game Center Sandbox

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center

Is there a way to clear out all data from the Game Center sandbox and start fresh, save creating a new app ID? I have a bunch of games that have bad data from testing that I can't get rid of.

Comment: goto itunes connect and clear testData in manage Game Center

Answer (score 1):

yes.you can. In the GameCenter management in you app,you can find the delete test data button.
hope this can help you .

Answer (score 1):

The trick above did not work for me.  My game still shows an incorrect highscore leaderboard count of 41779 due to an incorrect grab of an int out of NSUserDefaults.  I've requested the deletion of the test data multiple times and it's been over 24 hours already.  Perhaps it's a unique occurance, but yeah.. deletion does not seem to be resetting the score on the sandbox GameCenter.

If I'm missing anything, please share your 2 cents

Comment: For me it clears the scores but not the achievements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset achievements also try this code:

```
[GKAchievement resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error ===> %@", error);
    }
 }];
```